# If $A_{n} = \frac{a_{1}+...+a_{n}}{n}$ is convergent then, is $a_{n}$ bounded$?$

Tags: real-analysis

If $A_{n} = \frac{a_{1}+...+a_{n}}{n}$ is convergent then, is $a_{n}$ bounded$?$
I couldn't find any counter example to this.

I know that If $a_{n}$ is convergent then $A_{n}$ converges. But converse is false.
But, I just need to check the boundedness here.
Any hint$?$

Comment: What about $a_k = 0$ except $a_1 = 1, a_{11} = 10, a_{111} = 100, a_{1111} = 1000, \ldots$?  Then $A_k \leq 1$ for all $k$, but $a_k$ is unbounded.

Comment: No. Take a sequence of the type $(0,0,..,0,1,0,0....,0,2,0,0...,0,3,....)$ with 'lots of $0$'s'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $a_n=k$ if $n=k^3$ and $0$ otherwise.

Note that $A_{k^3}=\frac{1+\dots+k}{k^3}= \frac{k(k+1)}{2k^3} \rightarrow_k 0$.

For every $n$ there is a unique $k$ such that $k^3\leq n < (k+1)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_n=nA_n-(n-1)A_{n-1}=n(A_n-A_{n-1})+A_{n-1}$ and since $\{A_n\}$ converges, $\{a_n\}$ is bounded if and only if $\{n(A_n-A_{n-1})\}$ is bounded. However, one can take a convergent sequence $\{A_n\}$ such that $\{n(A_n-A_{n-1})\}$ is unbounded. For example, the sequence $\{A_n\}$ defined by
$$
A_n=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
converges, but the sequence $\{n(A_n-A_{n-1})\}=\{(-1)^{n-1}\sqrt{n}\}$ is unbounded. Hence, the converse is false.

Answer (score 0):

You may take the seqeunce with terms all zeros except the following $a_{10}=1, a_{100}=2....$ and so on... Then clearly $A_n$ tends to zero but $a_n$ is not bounded.